# Can I add a C array into a objective-C NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa

Can I add a C array into a objective-C NSArray?

```
NSArray * testArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
         @"obj1", 
         {"C array obj1", "C array obj2"},
          nil];
```

gives me `Expected Expression` message error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot add plain C arrays to `NSArray`.

But as storing a C array means storing a pointer, you can wrap that pointer into an `NSValue` and store that instead:

```
char *someCArray = ...;
NSArray *array = @[[NSValue valueWithPointer:someCArrray]];
```

Keep in mind that you are only storing the pointer - and memory management is still up to you.

Or you could wrap the memory of the array into some Objective-C object, like  `NSData`, but there should be very good reasons to go to such lengths.

My guess in the wild is - without knowing the concrete use case - that you're better of converting the C data into objects themselves and store them "the Objective-C" way.

Comment: Is there an inline notation so that I don't need to declare the variable someCarray?

Comment: @Patrick Where does the array come from, then? Some code must create it (and allocate its memory) - you certainly don't want to store a pointer to a short-lived slice of stack memory. And if you're just creating it, the question is, why use a C array here?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Indeed bad wording on my part. Will edit the answer.